# Unable to change order of Stacked bar chart data

Tags: crystal-reports, bar-chart, crystal-reports-xi, stacked-chart

I'm using Crystal 11.5 on the desktop. I'm having a problem where the stacked chart data is not appearing as I want. It appears like below, but I would like:

1) Completed on bottom, then Open on top, 
2) Completed should be blue color, Open orange.

I think once the data appears as I want, changing the color should be easy enough via manual manipulation.

[image]

[image]

I tried using a lot of different chart options and playing around with Specified Order as reversed (Open, Completed instead of Completed, Open). Nothing I've done has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the stacked data appear as I want, I needed to first create a cross tab (pivot table). Then right click on the cross tab and select Insert Chart.